# При отправке фото aiogram2 в определённое время(apscheduler) возникает ошибка

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, apscheduler

```
from datetime import datetime

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram import executor
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler

BOT_TOKEN = 'тут токен бота'
bot = Bot(token=BOT_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


async def send_message_cron(bot: Bot):
    # текстовое сообщение отправляется нормально
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=`тут id чата`, text='тут текст')
    # при отправке фото происходит ошибка, выписанная ниже
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=`тут id чата`, photo='downloads/orders.jpg')


scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(timezone="Europe/Moscow")
scheduler.add_job(send_message_cron,
                  trigger='cron',
                  hour=datetime.now().hour,
                  minute=datetime.now().minute + 1,
                  start_date=datetime.now(),
                  kwargs={'bot': bot})
scheduler.start()

if name == 'main':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

```
C:\Python3.11.1\python.exe C:\Users\Админ\PycharmProjects\OrderDinnerBot\test2.py 
Updates were skipped successfully.
Job "send_message_cron (trigger: cron[hour='23', minute='38'], next run at: 2023-10-05 23:38:00 MSK)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python3.11.1\Lib\site-packages\apscheduler\executors\base_py3.py", line 30, in run_coroutine_job
    retval = await job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Админ\PycharmProjects\OrderDinnerBot\test2.py", line 28, in send_message_cron
  File "C:\Python3.11.1\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 565, in send_photo
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_PHOTO, payload, files)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python3.11.1\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 236, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python3.11.1\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 140, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python3.11.1\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 115, in check_result
    exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
  File "C:\Python3.11.1\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 141, in detect
    raise cls(description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Wrong http url specified
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `send_photo` в качестве параметра `photo` принимает в себя не путь до этого изображения, а сам объект изображения. Данный объект можно получить из

```
from aiogram.types import InputFile
```

А затем задав отправку фотографии следующим образом

```
    image = InputFile('downloads/orders.png')
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id='ваш чат id', photo=image)
```

---

Можете так же воспользоваться `open`

```
    with open('Путь к изображению', 'rb') as photo:
       await bot.send_photo(chat_id='ваш чат id', photo)
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли!

Comment: @ՅուրաՊետրոսյան Если вам помог мой ответ, пометьте его как решение, используя галочку слева от моего ответа.